# Problem deserializing soap message on call back

Tags: c#, java, wcf, web-services, soap

I am implementing a WCF .NET service that is called back by another service.
The soap message that the call back service sends back is below

### The SOAP Message

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"                
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
<ns1:getAccountBalance soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://service.company.x.y">
  <param0 xsi:type="xsd:string">123-K</param0>
  <param1 xsi:type="xsd:string">551003</param1>
  <param2 xsi:type="xsd:string">123</param2>
  <param3 xsi:type="xsd:string">1231</param3>
  <param4 xsi:type="xsd:string">ug</param4>
  <param5 xsi:type="xsd:string">x</param5>
  <param6 xsi:type="xsd:string">1.0</param6>
</ns1:getAccountBalance>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

### The WCF contract to receive the messae

```
 [OperationContract(Action="")]
    AccountEnquiryResponse getAccountBalance(String param0, String param1, String param2, String param3, String param4, String param5, String param6);
```

### The service implilmentation

```
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "http://service.company.x.y")]
public class MyService:IService
{
    public AccountEnquiryResponse getAccountBalance(String param0, String param1, String param2, String param3, String param4, String param5, String param6)
    {
        return new AccountEnquiryResponse
```

### The problem

When the call back returns the WCF service is unable to deserialize the SOAP message parameters - they are all **null**

### A soap message that works

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
<getAccountBalance xmlns="http://service.company.x.y">
  <param0>123</param0>
  <param1>123</param1>
  <param2>uid</param2>
  <param3>pwd</param3>
  <param4>en</param4>
  <param5>ug</param5>
  <param6>1.0</param6>
</getAccountBalance>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

### My conclusion

The difference between the SOAP message that works and the one that does not work are the properties *soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/*" and  *xsi:type="xsd:string* on the parameters and .NET is unable to deserialize the object properly because of them.

Is that true?

What can i do to solve this problem?

PS. the service that calls me back is a third party application written in JAVA and I have no control over the message format that is sent back to my application.

Please advise

Comment: I found the problem. The soap message that does not work has <ns1:getAccountBalance and the one that does has <getAccountBalance. If i remove ns1 am able to deserialize the soap message correctly. Since i dont have control over the message ... my next problem is how to get .NET to play nice with nsi included

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to deal with the ns1 namespace issue? I have a feeling a similar thing is causing me issues.

Comment: Yes. .NET allows you to intercept messages before or just after receiving.  See code sample public class MMMessageInspector :  IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            request = TransformMessage(request);
            return null; 

        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
           //do nothing 
        }
You can then write code to remove the ns1

Answer (score 0):

Does .Net have an attribute for setting a namespace on the AccountEnquiryResponse object?  That will solve both your problems.

If you're the server, what did the client use to generate their stubs?  Did you give them a wsdl? or point them to your running server?  If you gave them a wsdl, did you use that same wsdl to generate *your* service interface?

This looks *realy* like two sides not using the same interface.  XML is really rather picky about fully qualified names.